# Postgis ST_Intersects for circle giving wrong values

Tags: google-maps-api-3, postgis

I need to return true when a particular point(lat/longs) is present inside my geofence circle. But the query is retuning true even though the point is outside my geofence circle.

Please find the query below.

select ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(geofence_polygon, 127.08), ST_POINT(18.595798 ,73.78833)) from masterdata.al_m_geofence

In this query, geofence_polygon is of type geography.

127.08 - radius of circle in meters

18.595798 - latitude

73.78833 - longitude

The query should return true only when the point is inside the circle.

Please let me know, whether this query is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your [ST_POINT arguments are backwards](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html):

```
geometry ST_Point(float x_lon, float y_lat);
```

Should be:

```
ST_POINT(73.78833,18.595798)
```

full query:

```
select ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(geofence_polygon, 127.08), ST_POINT(73.78833,18.595798)) from masterdata.al_m_geofence
```